# MultiSubnetFailover=true not working for listeners with multiple ips

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-string

My connection string looks as follows:

```xml
<add name="CONN_STRING" connectionString="Data Source=Listener1,28589;MultiSubnetFailover=True;Initial Catalog=DataDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxx" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

When I use Listener1 which has 1 active ip, it works fine. But when I use Listener2 which has 2 nodes (1 active, 1 inactive),it doesn't work.

My initial guess was that my application was using old libraries to make the connection. But the application works on a different machine.

Application is targeting .net 4.5.1 framework. And both machines have 4.6.2 installed. Is there anything else that I need to change?

This is the error I get when it doesn't work.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

Comment: This question isn't related to programming.  Post to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql-server.

Comment: It is about establishing connection between the application and the database using the connection string inside the application's web.config. So isn't it related to programming then?

Comment: What does "c:\>nslookup Listener2" return?

Comment: It returns just 1 ip address.

Answer (score 3):

Multi-Subnet-Fail-Over represents the possibility to cross the subnet in the database connection. Windows Server 2008 or later and SQL server 2012 is required because they have a logical OR sequence and use the AlwaysON AG configuration.
Windows 2003 and SQL server 2008 have a logical AND sequence and to be functional they need the clustered resource to remain online.
See doc Microsoft at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/listeners-client-connectivity-application-failover?view=sql-server-2017#SupportAgMultiSubnetFailover